# ¿Qué política tiene el sitio cuando un usuario se pone expresamente un nombre similar a otro?

Tags: soporte, moderación, usuarios

Como mucha gente del sitio sabe, mi nombre real es **Carlos Alejo** y como tal se me ha conocido durante más de un año aquí. Hace poco, y considerando que mi nombre completo queda demasiado formal para un sitio en el que me hallo entre amigos, decidí relajarme un poco y cambié mi apodo por **Charlie**, que es como muchos de mis amigos y compañeros de trabajo (y hasta algunos en mi familia) me conocen.

Hace poco, sin embargo, descubrí que un usuario reciente ha cambiado su apodo por [Carlos_Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17232/user17232). A estas alturas, y gracias a que tengo una imagen de avatar fácilmente reconocible, todos están ya acostumbrados a mi apodo "Charlie", pero eso no quita para que Carlos_Alejo haya causado confusión con algún que otro comentario (en los que no se incluye el avatar).

Sé que mi cambio de apodo causó algo de confusión en su día, pero este nuevo usuario puede causar aún más (de momento no se ha prodigado mucho tras su cambio de apodo).

La cuestión es, ¿cuál es la política del sitio (o de Stack Exchange) cuando pasan estas cosas? ¿Se puede obligar a este usuario a modificar su apodo para que no cause confusión? ¿O debo alegrarme por que alguien me haga semejante homenaje y reconocimiento, y dejar que la gente aprenda a distinguirnos?

Comment: There is obviously no Stack-wide policy as we have, for instance, six users called Carlos. On another site where I post we have a high-rep user Wolfgang, two other Wolfgang, a wolfgang and a WolfGang. So this issue seems to be up to us as a site.

Comment: @mdewey I wouldn't mind if the user just choses Carlos as his name, but taking also my last name seems suspicious, as Alejo is a very uncommon one.

Comment: Yes I agree, I was just trying to see if there was a site-wide policy about duplicate names and it seems there is not.

Comment: La postura de los moderadores es contundente: "Voy a tener que exigirte que te cambies el alias de la cuenta a otro que no cause confusión sobre la identidad de la persona tras la cuenta. Con el alias que tienes ahora, la autoría de tus contribuciones puede no quedar clara, y esto puede ser perjudicial para otros usuarios.
... esta petición de cambiarte el alias de la cuenta a otro que no cause confusión sobre la identidad de la persona tras la cuenta **no es negociable**.

Comment: @user17232 Lo es. Como puedes ver en esta pregunta tu elección de apodo ha causado confusión y el resto de los usuarios teme que vaya a peor. Tu elección de apodo no parece aportar ningún valor o beneficio y otros usuarios se sienten molestos y perjudicados por lo que se puede entender por un intento de suplantación o un ataque personal. Valoramos mucho tus contribuciones, pero la forma que tienes de actuar fuerza nuestra mano, ya que no podemos permitir que otros usuarios se vean perjudicados por este tipo de actos.

Comment: Comentario adicional: como ya he aclarado con @Charlie en chat, cuando cambié de nombre a Carlos_Alejo después de que él cambiara de nick tuve especial cuidado en a) esperar un tiempo y b) no usar exactamente el mismo (de ahí el guión bajo), para evitar posibles confusiones y fue como homenaje a su trayectoria, no para molestar, crear confusiones o adornarme con camándulas ajenas. Sin embargo, veo que si produjo confusiones y le molestó, por lo que los moderadores me exigieron que cambiara el nick, cosa que no podía hacer yo (hay un tiempo establecido entre cambios de nombre)...

Comment: - por lo que los moderadores me lo cambiaron *nolens volens* al nombre por defecto de *user17232* que no podré cambiar hasta noviembre. En el chat con @Charlie ya le he pedido directamente disculpas y ahora aquí aprovecho para pedirlas a los demás a los que ese cambio de nombre ha podido confundir.

Comment: @user y qué nombre de usuario querrías usar? Porque con _moo_ y esa imagen de perfil ya estabas utilizando el de otra persona...

Comment: @fedorqui: como hasta el 4 o 5 de noviembre no puedo hacer nada, ni me lo planteo. Pero seguramente lo iré cambiando periódicamente.

Comment: @user17232 haz lo que consideres, pero ten en cuenta lo que te hemos dicho en mensaje privado y en mi respuesta. Todos te queremos en la comunidad y todos queremos una comunidad amable.

Comment: @fedorqui si prefieres que no cambie el nombre de usuario y siga permanentemente como **user17232**, no hay problema (aunque no es un nombre de usuario que me vuelva loco de pasión)

Comment: @user17232 hace poco precisamente tuvimos el caso contrario: un usuario llamado "userXXXXX" (no me acuerdo el número) que estaba adquiriendo una buena reputación por sus aportaciones, y le pedimos que se lo cambiara por algo más reconocible. Puedes seguir como "user17232", pero nos alegraría que eligieras un nombre que sientas como tuyo para que los demás podamos reconocerte. Es simplemente por hacer la convivencia más fácil.

Comment: @user17232 como dije anteriormente, eres libre de hacer lo que consideres, siempre y cuando tu decisión se encuadre dentro de la filosofía [_Be nice_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @user17232, Gracias por aclarar las cosas con Carlos Alejo. No dudes en contactar con los moderadores si podemos ayudarte con tu cuenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No parece que haya una política muy definida para este caso concreto. He encontrado algún debate al respecto:

- Meta.SE [How to handle people impersonating other people by choosing the same display name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38466/209901)
- Meta.SE [The community position towards role playing in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216725/209901)
- Meta.SO [Why are we allowing usernames such as “stackoverflow”, “stack overflow” and “moderator”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280033/1983854)

Y todos tienden al mismo punto: cada cual puede usar el nombre de usuario que le apetezca, siempre y cuando no se haga para suplantar o engañar a nadie.

En este caso no parece que la intención sea ninguna de las dos, pero colisiona con una norma más elemental y que subyace en toda la comunidad: [Be nice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) (es decir, [compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)). *Be nice* quiere decir fomentar una buena convivencia, *be nice* quiere decir que tu presencia mejore el sitio y haga más apetecible la estancia a los demás, *be nice* quiere decir ser maduro.

Este usuario lleva tiempo jugando al límite y vuelve con regularidad con nuevas identidades. Hace unas semanas se entretuvo utilizando antiguas imágenes de perfil que yo utilicé; hace meses, ridiculizando mi nombre de usuario con unas variantes hirientes. Que haya utilizado tu nombre de usuario es, pues, una nueva manera de no ser *nice* a la comunidad generando líos innecesarios.

Como en paralelo publica preguntas y respuestas muy documentadas y útiles, no vemos motivos para bloquearlo absolutamente, pero estamos atentos para bloquear los comportamientos que se salgan de lo agradable para el sitio. En base a ello, **hemos procedido a modificar su nombre de usuario**.

Lamentamos las molestias que esto te haya ocasionado y llamamos a la cordura a este usuario: tiene paciencia y perseverancia, pero nosotros también y, además, somos cuatro :)

Referencias:

- [¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2602/1674)

PD: Disculpad que no podamos dar más datos, pero sería contraproducente explicar de qué herramientas disponemos para gestionar estas *situaciones*.