# Creación masiva de cuentas de spam

Tags: soporte, cuentas-de-usuario

Llevamos desde ayer miércoles 5 de junio (que yo me haya dado cuenta) sufriendo una creación masiva de cuentas de spam, tal y como se atestigua por la ingente cantidad de medallas *Autobiographer* que se están otorgando:

[image: Autobiographer badges in a row]

Como se ve, todas las cuentas tienen nombres de comercios, y de hecho las descripciones en sus autobiografías son todas del mismo estilo:

[image: Spam]

Escribo esto simplemente para ponerlo en conocimiento de los moderadores, y de paso para que nos expliquen cómo se procede en estos casos:

- ¿No se hace nada?
- ¿Se eliminan todas las cuentas creadas en una franja de tiempo a mano?
- ¿Se trata de detectar la IP desde la que se crean y se eliminan todas automáticamente?
- En caso de que se requiera alguna acción, ¿la podemos ejecutar nosotros, o hay que avisar a más altas instancias?

Comment: Intentaré escribir una respuesta detallada cuando tenga tiempo pero básicamente, no creo que un mod pueda/deba elimiar cuentas solo por una sospecha. Con las _mod tools_ uno puede hacer ciertas indagaciones para ver si hay algún tipo de infracción (se están votando entre ellas? Son un mal uso de _sockpuppets_). Los mods no tenemos manera de hacer tareas como esa eliminación masiva, así que habría que ponerlo en conocimiento de los CM. Hay una sala de chat espacial para mods, y merecería la pena ver si otros stacks están experimentado lo mismo.

Comment: Así que básicamente: gran descubrimiento (gracias por estar tan atento), gracias por ponerlo en conocimiento de la comunidad y los mods, y supongo que lo avisaremos y escalaremos el problema a los community managers.

Answer (score 3):

**Gran descubrimiento**

Los moderadores no podemos tomarnos la libertad de borrar cuentas de usuario. Algunas cuentas pueden estar inactivas por mucho tiempo, otras pueden ser creadas por error, o pueden ser un [uso legítimo de un sockpuppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65604/356575).

Los moderadores no tenemos herramientas que permitan hacer algunas de las cosas que propones (como eliminar a la vez todas las cuentas con una determinada condición, ya sea la franja de tiempo y/o la IP de la cuenta), pero desde luego sí tenemos algunas para indagar qué pasa con esas cuentas en este caso.

Este sí parece ser un problema legítimo, ya que investigando esas cuentas (sin revelar mucho de la información privilegiada a la que los moderadores tenemos acceso), parece ser que hay un gran número de cuentas, creadas en espacio de algunos días, que comparten IP.

Este elevado número es motivo suficiente para elevar el problema a los *community managers* y dejar que lo investiguen y gestionen ellos, sin necesidad de considerar si es un uso legítimo o no de las múltiples cuentas.

Merece la pena recordar que hace tiempo los moderadores publicamos [¿Cómo deben gestionarse las cuentas títere en Stack Exchange?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2602/5481) para dar a conocer (o recordar) a la comunidad las normas acerca del uso de múltiples cuentas y qué es una infracción y qué es un suso legítimo al respecto, además de explicar un poco cómo actuamos para investigar posibles problemas relacionados con este tema.

Parece ser que otros stacks (no todos) también han experimentado un problema similar con la creación masiva de lo que parecen ser cuentas de spam, por lo que al reportarlo has ayudado de manera directa o indirecta a otros *stacks* aparte del nuestro.

Gracias de nuevo por reportar este hallazgo.

Answer (score 3):

Este problema es, desgraciadamente, tan viejo como Stack Exchange:

- [Is spam in the "about me" field a reason to worry?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105218/209901)

Y hay moderadores que han pedido herramientas para combatirlo:

- [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/209901)

Sin embargo, la política oficial de Stack Exchange parece centrada en asumir que es algo inevitable y no excesivamente lesivo. Como indica Jeff Atwood en la respuesta a la primera pregunta:

> Note that
>
> - Links in your "about me" field don't work for low-rep users; we don't allow more than 2 links by new users in this field, and they aren't actually hyperlinked until you have 15 rep.
> - The "website" field is not hyperlinked until you generate 15 rep.
>
> ... so the damage potential here is small

Otros arguyen que esta información acaba colándose en los motores de búsqueda, por lo que es contraproducente. Y de ahí entiendo la perseverancia de las empresas que crean usuarios así.

---

Dicho todo esto, en mi opinión no hay que preocuparse demasiado. Somos un sitio al que los spammers no han puesto en su radar (otros sitios de similar tamaño sí reciben) y cuando algo entra en forma de publicaciones o ediciones perniciosas lo atajamos rápida y contundentemente.

Comment: Más que el spam en la sección "about me" me preocupaba la creación masiva de dichas cuentas, pero gracias por compartir esta información, es sin duda de utilidad, y explica por qué los vínculos no estaban activados en estos perfiles. :-)