# Proposing moderatorhood

Tags: discusión, moderación

This is a formal proposal to add Charlie
[image: Charlie to the rescue] to our crack team of moderators.

[Diego described](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/uno-entre-catorce-mil-enhorabuena-charlie-por-llegar-a-50-k#comment5827_3096) Charlie's contributions to the site better than I could:

> preguntas muy interesantes, respuestas geniales e increíblemente bien documentadas (a veces a preguntas que ya considerábamos "irresolubles"), trato cortés a todos los usuarios, usuario modelo y un ejemplo a seguir

Most recent reason: quick [notification](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/creaci%C3%B3n-masiva-de-cuentas-de-spam) to moderators about possible mass sock puppet creation.

Comment: In our current state (meaning, being a **beta site**) we are pretty limited as of what we can do in regards of appointing new mods. Some beta stacks have had moderator elections. It would be up to the whole community (and not just the mods) to move things so there is a formal process of election in which Charlie (among others) could be proposed as a candidate. Meaning, this post could get a 100 upvotes and it would still be up to the CM, who could just say that there is no need for a fifth mod, so I believe that the discussion you just started might be boarder than what you initially intended.

Comment: @Diego - Thanks for the quick response!  First: We have four mods on the books but everyone knows you and fedorqui shoulder *more* than 95% of the weight.  Secondly: I'll go through any hoops there might be (within reason).   Guidance regarding those hoops might be would be much appreciated.  (But I realize this may take some time and thought.)

Comment: I am flattered by your confidence in my moderation abilities. If the current moderators  consider me worthy and ask me to help them I'll be honoured to do so. But in the meantime I don't consider being a moderator one of my current goals in the site. Right now I prefer to focus on writing good posts, but thanks again for your proposal.

Comment: @walen - One of Charlie's virtues is his humility.  If anyone's going to put his name forward, it's not likely to be him.  And he might not have given serious thought to being a moderator recently.  But I hope he will, and I hope others will support his nomination. //  I trust Diego and Fedorqui to let Charlie find the level of involvement that feels right to him.

Comment: @Charlie - Hey, thanks for weighing in.  I don't know what the process is but I will stay tuned and see what is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I am the first one to think Charlie could be a very good mod. This comes first!

It is also important to know what the procedure is. For this, comments like:

> Guidance regarding those hoops might be would be much appreciated
>
> I don't know what the process is but I will stay tuned and see what is recommended.

... shock me a bit. I mean, aparente, you've been a Stack Exchange user for 4+ years. You know how to find things and that there are some procedures and, honestly, I don't like the tone of 'Hey I would like this, please make it happen.'

Some basic ideas (relevant posts are easy to find):

- Beta sites have Pro Tem moderators.
- Traditionally, those Pro Tem moderators were appointed by CMs:

  - I was emailed by a CM on a given moment and said yes.
  - For Diego, I asked CMs for suppoet, since I noticed most of the workload was on my side.
- Lately a Pro Tem election system has been put in place and several Beta sites have been using it. I checked with CMs some months ago and we can eventualy ask for it.

That being said, adding a member to the mod team needs to be considered, specially by the current mod team. Having someone new on board means adjusting dynamics and it is desirable to have someone with a good vibe, honest, objective and able to eventually defend positions they are not entirely happy with (I know Charlie would do great on all of this).

As a mod you see the dark side of the site, with trolls, people that want to make you lose some time and people that are just weird. Also, it comes with a red button to whatever you touch that makes things get resolved onehandedly, and not as a part of a collegiated decision.
For Diego and me, for example, it means that we are not expected to attend the review queues much, which is something we used to do often back on our non-mod life in Spanish.SE.

95% of private messages to users were sent by either Diego or me. Time of flag handling has drecreased to less than the half to what was before. +80% of deleted posts were done by either Diego or me. I think also that Meta has had quite a lot of movement over the last three years.

We all know things can always go better. However, it is just that asking for a new mod for the sake of it is not always 'the' solution, because it can have unnecessary drawbacks.

Comment: I have done some research but I did not find a clear procedure I could follow.  If there is one and I missed it, you are welcome to scold me for not finding it if you want to, but I hope that in addition you will give me a link to the clear procedure.  // But my guess is that this is a slightly fuzzy area. // I don't want to push you and Diego into a new operating mode if it doesn't feel right at this time; however, from everything that I've seen of how you two and Charlie interact here, I am extremely optimistic that the three of you would work out how you want the collaboration to ...

Comment: work, if Charlie were to end up joining the moderating team. // I am sticking my neck out with this proposal for several reasons: (1) it seems like a natural direction of growth for Charlie, (2)  I'd like to give you two the opportunity to have a third active person on the team to help out, and (3) the site is growing and I think having an additional gardener to tend it, can help it continue to grow.